# SMTP Error 535 (Incorrect authentication data) using PEAR mail

Tags: php, smtp, pear

I used the code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2748837 to attempt to log into both Gmail and my website's server, and for both of them I received the same error:

```
authentication failure [SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: 535, response: Incorrect authentication data)]
```

I have double- and triple-checked that the usernames and passwords are correct (since it works from a desktop client), and removed the brackets around the username. What could be the problem?

Comment: how are you sending the email ?

Comment: using the code from http://stackoverflow.com/a/2748837.